# how to random data without repeat

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, button

Quiz 1: this code can randomize the question but the problem is they still random the duplicate question. for example,when the user answer the question, the next question also view the same question.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
public class Quiz1 extends Activity {

    Button mButtonChoice1, mButtonChoice2, mButtonChoice3;

    TextView mScoreView, mQuestionView;

    private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionNumber = mQuestionLibrary.mQuestions.length;

    Random r;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz1);

        r = new Random();


        mButtonChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice3);

        mScoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);

        mScoreView.setText(" " + mScore);

        updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionNumber));


        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer){
                    mScore++;
                    mScoreView.setText(" " + mScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionNumber));
                    if (mScore == 10){
                        success();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(Quiz1.this, "betul", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz1.this, "salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gameOver();
                }
            }
        });

        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer){
                    mScore++;
                    mScoreView.setText(" " + mScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionNumber));

                    if (mScore == 10){
                        success();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz1.this, "betul", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz1.this, "salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gameOver();
                }
            }
        });


        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer){
                    mScore++;
                    mScoreView.setText(" " + mScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionNumber));
                    if (mScore == 10){
                        success();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz1.this, "betul", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz1.this, "salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gameOver();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    private void updateQuestion(int num){
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(num));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(num));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(num));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(num));

        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(num);

    }
    private void gameOver(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Quiz1.this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Tamat! Skor anda ialah  " + mScore + " markah.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Cuba lagi",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quiz1.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    private void success(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Quiz1.this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Berjaya! Skor anda adalah " + mScore + " markah.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Pelajaran seterusnya",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LessonMenu.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**QuestionLibrary.java**

package com.example.fyp_menjahit;

public class QuestionLibrary {

```
    public String mQuestions [] = {
            "Apakah nama jahitan di dalam video sebentar tadi?",
            "Jahitan tersebut sesuai digunakan untuk?",
            "Berapakah anggaran jarak untuk menjahit jahitan ini...",
            "Diantara berikut, yang manakah langkah awal sebelum menjahit jahitan jelujur kasar?",
            "Antara berikut,yang manakah merupakan bahan jahitan yang betul untuk menjahit jahitan jelujur kasar?",
            "Apakah alatan jahitan yang boleh digunakan dalam menjahit untuk membetulkan jahitan sekiranya berlaku kesalahan?",
            "Adakah jahitan di dalam video sebentar tadi adalah jahitan kia?",
            "Jahitan tersebut sesuai digunakan untuk?",
            "______________ digunakan untuk melekatkan 2 atau lebih fabrik.",
            "Bahan yang diperlukan untuk menjahit jahitan jelujur kasar?"
    };


    private String mChoices [][] = {
            {"Jelujur Halus", "Jelujur Kasar", "Jelujur Tegak"},
            {"untuk melekatkan 2 atau lebih lapisan fabrik", "untuk menjahit butang", "untuk hiasan"},
            {"10mm", "3-5mm", "6mm"},
            {"memasukkan benang ke dalam jarum", "terus menjahit", "memilih fabrik yang cantik"},
            {"benang,pisau lipat, kain", "benang, jarum, gunting", "kertas, kain, benang"},
            {"gam", "gunting", "surat khabar"},
            {"ya", "tidak", "-"},
            {"untuk melekatkan 2 atau lebih lapisan fabrik", "untuk menjahit butang", "untuk hiasan"},
            {"Jahitan kia", "Jahitan jelujur kasar", "Insang pari"},
            {"benang, besi", "benang, jarum, kain", "besi, kain"}
    };



    private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {"Jelujur Kasar", "untuk melekatkan 2 atau lebih lapisan fabrik", "10mm", "memasukkan benang ke dalam jarum", "benang, jarum, gunting",
            "gunting", "tidak", "untuk melekatkan 2 atau lebih lapisan fabrik", "Jahitan jelujur kasar", "benang, jarum, kain"};




    public String getQuestion(int a) {
        String question = mQuestions[a];
        return question;
    }


    public String getChoice1(int a) {
        String choice = mChoices[a][0];
        return choice;
    }


    public String getChoice2(int a) {
        String choice = mChoices[a][1];
        return choice;
    }

    public String getChoice3(int a) {
        String choice = mChoices[a][2];
        return choice;
    }


    public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        String answer = mCorrectAnswers[a];
        return answer;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a List, add all possible values to it, and shuffle it.

Basically, create a new ArrayList of type Integer, add the numbers from 1 to mQuestionNumber, and shuffle the list. Then iterate over it.

Something like this (basic example):

```
public class randomizedListTest {
    private static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mQuestionNumber; i++) {
            list.add(i); //adds all values to the list
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list); //this randomizes the list

        for (int i = 0; i < mQuestionNumber; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i)); //This should print the all numbers from 0 to mQuestionNumber in random order.
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's the Javadoc entry on Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))